# What should I call a REBOL function that does list comprehensions?

Tags: list-comprehension, naming, rebol, dialect

REBOL has no built-in way to perform list comprehensions. However, REBOL has a powerful facility (known as `parse`) that can be used to create domain-specific languages (DSLs). I've used `parse` to create such a mini-DSL for list comprehensions. In order to interpret the expression, the block containing the comprehension is passed to a function, which for lack of a better term I've called `comprehend`.

**Example:**

```
comprehend [(a * b) for a in 1x100 for b in 4x10 where (all [odd? a odd? b])]
```

For some reason, `comprehend` doesn't sound right to me, but something like `eval` is too general.

I haven't found any other language that requires a keyword or function for list comprehensions. They are pure syntactic sugar wherever they exist. Unfortunately I don't have that option. So, seeing that I must have a function, what's a good, succinct, logical name for it?

Comment: Here's the source code for the list comprehension: http://blog.revolucent.net/2009/04/dirt-simple-dsl-in-rebol.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `select`?

`select [(a * b) for a in 1x100 for b in 4x10 where (all [odd? a odd? b])]`

Comment: Rebol already has a `select` function, and it's important. Not this name.

Answer (score 2):

Because list comprehensions can be thought of as analogous to map, you might think about calling it something like "listmap". Alternately, because list comprehensions are based on set-builder notation, you could call it something along the lines of "build" or "buildlist".

(Disclaimer: I know very little about REBOL, so forgive me if these names are already taken)

Answer (score 2):

transmogrify

Answer (score 1):

`do` could be appropriate, as list comprehensions are just one instance of Monad comprehensions, and `do` is the keyword used in Haskell for sugared Monadic computations but I suspect it's too vague for a user library. I called my list comprehension function `comp`, but that's just an abbreviation of what you already have. Perhaps `yielding`? E.g. `yielding [(a * b) for a in 1x100 for b in 4x10 where (all [odd? a odd? b])]`. Just sort of squint and pretend the [ ] aren't there.